# Dictionary with list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

My data is a dictionary with a list of dictionaries inside.

```
data = {'John': [{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'10'}, {'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'9'}], 'Maria': [{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Maria', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'10'}, {'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Maria', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'9'}], 'Roger': [{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Roger', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'10'}, {'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Roger', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'9'}], 'Peter': [{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Peter', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'10'}, {'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Peter', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'9'}]}
```

What I am trying to do is to have a dataframe of the list of dictionaries inside each data.key

I start by:
    mydf = df(data.keys())

```
mydf
Out[18]: 
       0
0   John
1  Roger
2  Peter
3  Maria
```

Than I try to have the df.data inside each dict.key

```
mydf(df(data))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-43-5c9743ed39d1>", line 1, in <module>
    mydf(df(data))

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

My final goal is to define a function to write a csv for each key with the datatrame inside.

My question is how can I put the datraframe inside the dictionary key, for each key the correspondent dataframe.

desired output for each dict.key to be stored in a csv:

```
name  date      fieldname fieldvalue   
Roger 20180301  lunch      12
Roger 20180301  dinner     12
Roger 20180301  lunch      12
Roger 20180301  dinner     12
```

Comment: show us your expected output for above data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'John': [{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'10'}, 
{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'John', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'9'}], 
'Maria': [{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Maria', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'10'}, 
{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Maria', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'9'}], 
'Roger': [{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Roger', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'10'}, 
{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Roger', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'9'}], 
'Peter': [{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Peter', 'fieldname': u'lunch', 'fieldvalue': u'10'}, 
{'date': u'2018-01-21', 'name' : u'Peter', 'fieldname': u'dinner', 'fieldvalue': u'9'}]}

new_data = []
for key, value in data.items():
    new_data.extend(value)
df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns  = ['name', 'date', 'fieldname', 'fieldvalue'])
```

DataFrame Results:

```
    name        date fieldname fieldvalue
0   John  2018-01-21     lunch         10
1   John  2018-01-21    dinner          9
2  Maria  2018-01-21     lunch         10
3  Maria  2018-01-21    dinner          9
4  Roger  2018-01-21     lunch         10
5  Roger  2018-01-21    dinner          9
6  Peter  2018-01-21     lunch         10
7  Peter  2018-01-21    dinner          9
```

With this, it should be a piece of cake to write the pandas dataframe to a csv.

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `concatenate` function from numpy, it can be done in one line.

```
# convert dictionary to data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(list(np.concatenate(list(data.values()))))

# write the file
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)

# print 
print(df)

         date   fieldname   fieldvalue  name
0   2018-01-21      lunch           10  John
1   2018-01-21     dinner            9  John
2   2018-01-21      lunch           10  Maria
3   2018-01-21     dinner            9  Maria
4   2018-01-21      lunch           10  Roger
5   2018-01-21     dinner            9  Roger
6   2018-01-21      lunch           10  Peter
7   2018-01-21     dinner            9  Peter
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` to unpack `data`:

```
from functools import reduce # if python2, delete this line.
df = pd.DataFrame(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list(data.values())))
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: using this df = pd.DataFrame(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list(data.values()])) I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @AmiB, sorry I got an input error, I correct it, check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (fieldname, fieldvalue) in data.iteritems():
    print fieldname
    print df(fieldvalue)


John
         date fieldname fieldvalue  name
0  2018-01-21     lunch         10  John
1  2018-01-21    dinner          9  John

Roger
         date fieldname fieldvalue   name
0  2018-01-21     lunch         10  Roger
1  2018-01-21    dinner          9  Roger

Peter
         date fieldname fieldvalue   name
0  2018-01-21     lunch         10  Peter
1  2018-01-21    dinner          9  Peter

Maria
         date fieldname fieldvalue   name
0  2018-01-21     lunch         10  Maria
1  2018-01-21    dinner          9  Maria
```